# Geometric transformations in Olympiad problems - Putnam 2001, A-4

Tags: contest-math, geometric-transformation

I have been reading Pasumarty's article [*A Fine Use of Transformations*](https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2016-04/article2_affine-transformations.pdf) in *Mathematical Reflections* 4 (2016).

The first part of the article deals with question A-4 on Putnam 2001:

> Triangle $ABC$ has an area $1$. Points $E$, $F$, $G$ lie, respectively, on $BC$, $CA$,
> $AB$ such that $AE$ bisects $BF$ at point $R$, $BF$
> bisects $CG$ at point $S$, and $CG$ bisects $AE$ at point $T$. Find the area of the
> triangle $RST$.

I have already read the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801229/affine-transformations-technique-putnam-2001-a-4), but I don't understand the following sentence in Pasumarty's article:

> By symmetry in the equilateral case, we can see that $\dfrac{AG}{AB} = \dfrac{BE}{BC} = \dfrac{CF}{CA}  = r$.

How can I formally prove the equality of these ratios if $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle? I tried to consider the clockwise (or counterclockwise) rotation of $120^{\circ}$ about the center of the triangle, that maps $ABC$ to itself, but I can't prove that the image of $AG$ is $BE$, the image of $BE$ is $CF$ and the image of $CF$ is $AG$, or something similar.

Comment: I think it's a logical flaw in that article. We don't know *a priori* that the resulting picture is symmetric, although by some continuity argument one can "show" that a symmetric solution *exists*. But the whole article (as probably the whole Euclidean geometry) is not really logically rigorous, according to modern standards.

Comment: @WhatsUp The article has some flaws (and the solution is transcribed second-hand, apparently; I have faith that Sam Zbarsky adressed this point) but you shouldn't be that dismissive of Euclidean geometry as a whole. Its logical rigor has been in fine shape at least since Hilbert in 1899.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I did say "according to modern standards". Even Hilbert's axioms have [known issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms#Application), mostly the reliance on an accurate diagram.

Comment: @WhatsUp If your standards for a lack of issues are "has been verified by computer proof" then 99% of modern mathematics is not really logically rigorous. If one of the many geometric statements Hilbert proved needs some extra thinking to resolve, that's an incredibly minor issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at just one pair of lines with one condition: $G$ is a point on line $AB$, and $BF$ bisects $CG$ at point $S$.

If $\frac{AG}{AB} = r$ and $\frac{CF}{CA} = s$, we can find a relationship between $r$ and $s$. For example, using areas: since $S$ bisects $CG$, $[BFG] = [BFC]$. We have $[BFC] = s \cdot [ABC]$, and $$[BFG] = (1-r) \cdot [BFA] = (1-r) \cdot (1-s) \cdot [ABC],$$ so $s = (1-r)(1-s)$, which is easiest to write as $r = 1- \frac{s}{1-s} = \frac{1-2s}{1-s}$.

The actual algebraic relationship is not super important to this step, but I derive it to give a rigorous proof of an intuitive fact: as $s$ increases, $r$ decreases, and vice versa.

The same relationship must hold between any two of the three ratios, by an identical proof.

---

Now suppose that (for a fixed equilateral $\triangle ABC$) there are multiple possible ways to draw $AE, BF, CG$ that satisfy the condition. Choose one with the maximum possible value of $\frac{AG}{AB}$. Then it must have the minimum possible value of $\frac{CF}{CA}$. Then it must have the *maximum* possible value of $\frac{BE}{BC}$, from which we deduce that actually it has the *minimum* possible value of $\frac{AG}{AB}$. In other words, only one value of $\frac{AG}{AB}$, and similarly only one value of $\frac{CF}{CA}$ and $\frac{BE}{BC}$, is possible.

Having shown uniqueness, we are finally ready to look at what happens when we apply the $120^\circ$ rotation that takes $A$ to $B$, $B$ to $C$, and $C$ to $A$. In general, this takes the points $E,F,G$ to points $E', F', G'$ such that segments $A'E'$, $B'F'$, and $C'G'$ satisfy the condition in the problem; in other words, $BE'$, $CF'$, and $AG'$ have the property we want. But because the solution is unique, we must have $E'=F$, $F'=G$, and $G'=E$. From this, $AG=CF=BE$ in the equilateral case follows.